# Проблема с импортом в python

Tags: python

Структура файлов такова:

```
/main
    /classes
        __init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
    __init__.py
    c.py
```

Суть проблемы: классы, которые лежат в `a.py` и `b.py` должны наследоваться от базового класса, одним из атрибутов которого является класс, который лежит в `c.py`. Я думаю, что это хорошая идея -- хранить базовые классы в `__init__.py` просто чтобы в папках не валялось лишних файлов.

На вот такую попытку импорта класса `с` компилятор начинает ругаться:

```
from .main.c import ClassC
# from .c import ClassC

Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Документация как-то не очень помогла и я не особо понимаю суть проблемы.

**PS.** Не рассмотрел ещё возможность запихивания файла `c.py` в отдельный каталог на том же уровне, но что-то подсказывает мне, что результат будет тот же.

Comment: Возможно, вам будет полезен также ответ на этот [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420987/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-init-py/420994#420994)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка говорит, что родительская директория main (не сама main папка) не являются Питон пакетом (Python package), т.е. там нет (ожидаемо) `__init__.py`.

Формально, исправить это можно используя `from ..c import ClassC` на уровне `a.py` (две точки, чтобы до родителя дойти). Но более понятно и надёжно будет использовать абсолютный импорт:

```
from main.c import ClassC
```

В целом, программируя на Питоне следует использовать меньше церемоний, в частности не следует помещать каждый публичный класс в отдельный модуль только потому что это публичный класс. main, classes также являются плохими именами так как они слишком общие (я надеюсь что это просто имена, используемые для вопроса и main имеет более уникальное имя). classes пакет не обязателен, не следует создавать вложенные пакеты без необходимости, можно использовать плоскую структуру: `<package>/{__init__,a,b,c}.py`:

```
>>> import this
...
Flat is better than nested.
...
```

Comment: @jfs пока писал свой ответ, их появилось ещё несколько. Все названия, разумеется, выбраны в качестве примера, реальные примеры намного сложнее и там каждый класс имеет минимум 100 строк. Не самые великие размеры, но я предпочту 5 файлов по 100, чем 1 в 500. Ну а когда в папке валяется больше 10 файлов, то навигация между ними тоже становится не очень удобной. Хотя...

**ЗЫ** В исходном примере файл `__init__.py` лежал, но интерпретатор почему-то всё равно ругался и я не мог понять, почему.

Answer (score 2):

в a.py просто

```
from main.c import Class
```

без . перед main

Comment: Да, а если вы хотите хранить все классы, которые потом будете наследовать, в main/__init__.py, вообще можно будет просто импортировать их как

    from main import Class

Хотя init чуток не для этого предназначен.

Comment: +1. `main.c.Class` можно упомянуть в `main/__init__.py`, если `Class` является публичным интерфейсом для `main`. Если он используется только внутри (a, b пакетами), то не следует его в `main/__init__.py` экспортировать.

Comment: @Ekkertan, а для чего предназначен `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы всё сработало как надо, необходимо, чтобы исполняемый файл лежал на уровень выше всех остальных файлов, тогда все относительные импорты будут работать. Пример:

```
main/
    main.py
    code/
        __init__.py
        abc.py
        classes/
            __init__.py
            a.py
            b.py

# main/code/abc.py
class ClassC( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super( ClassC, self ).__init__()
        self.c = 15

    def PrintC( self ):
        print self.c

# main/code/classes/__init__.py
from ..abc import ClassC

class BaseClass( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        super( BaseClass, self ).__init__()
        self.class_c = ClassC()

    def GetClassC( self ):
        return self.class_c

# main/code/classes/a.py
from . import BaseClass

class ClassA( BaseClass ):
    """docstring for ClassA"""
    def __init__( self, a ):
        super( ClassA, self ).__init__()
        self.a = a

    def PrintA( self ):
        print self.a

# main/code/classes/b.py
from . import BaseClass

class ClassB( BaseClass ):
    """docstring for ClassB"""
    def __init__( self, b ):
        super( ClassB, self ).__init__()
        self.b = b

    def PrintB( self ):
        print self.b

# main/main.py
from code.classes.a import ClassA
from code.classes.b import ClassB

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = ClassA( 5 )
    b = ClassB( 10 )
    c = a.GetClassC()
    a.PrintA()
    b.PrintB()
    c.PrintC()
```

Ну и вывод программы:

```
5
10
15
```

Проблема примера в том, что он сугубо абстрактный, и, не смотря на всю его кажущуюся простоту, разобраться в нём не так уж просто: всего у нас пять файлов, которые лежат в трёх вложенных папках.

Answer (score 0):

Или прописать путь в python_path, или читай [офф доки](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports)