# Обращение к функции заданной в __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, pip

При инициализации пакета в Python 2.7, мне нужно определить функции, которые должны быть общими для всех модулей данного пакета. Я определил их в `__init__.py`. Как теперь к ней обратиться внутри пакета? Извне получается так:

```
import package.module
package.foo() #обращение
```

Внутри пакета (например в модуле `module`), не определено `foo`, `dir(__package__)` - так же не выводит этой функции.

Структура проекта:

```
package\         # пакет
    __init__.py  # здесь функция
    module.py    # здесь мне функцию нужно вызвать
```

Названия, естественно, отличаются.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Исправлено**

На самом деле, файл **__init__.py** не предназначен для хранения реализации общих для пакета функций. Их предлагается выносить в другие файлы.

Вот что говорится в [документации](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> <...> In the simplest case, **__init__.py** can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

Цитата с [python-guide.org](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/):

> <...> special behavior for the **__init__.py** file, which is used to gather all package-wide definitions.
>
> <...>
>
> Leaving an **init**.py file empty is considered normal and even a good practice, if the package’s modules and sub-packages do not need to share any code.
>
> Lastly, a convenient syntax is available for importing deeply nested packages: import very.deep.module as mod. This allows you to use mod in place of the verbose repetition of very.deep.module.

---

Таким образом, **__init__.py** нужен для того, чтобы настроить представление реализации пакета для использующих его скриптов. Например, с помощью переменной `__all__` вы можете управлять видимыми подмодулями, или импортировать какой-то класс на уровень модуля.

Так что ответом на ваш вопрос будет то, что сейчас у вас неправильно распределена реализация функций по файлам, и стоит создать отдельный файл с реализацией нужных вам функций, а не хранить их в **__init__.py**.

---

Например, если у вас сейчас есть функция `boo` в файле **__init__.py**, вы можете вынести её в файл **module.py**, при необходимости вынеся её на уровень пакета, добавив следующую строку в ваш файл **__init__.py**:

```
# файл package/__init__.py
from module import boo
```

и для внешнего кода, импортирующего ваш модуль, она станет доступна не только через прямой импорт

```
# файл my_script.py
from package.module import boo
```

но и через импорт из пакета:

```
# файл my_script.py
from package import boo          # та же функция
```

---

Источники:

- [Документация](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)
- [Объяснение использования файла **__init__.py**](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html)
- [python-guide.org](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/)

Comment: Django пишет что нет такого модуля.

Comment: @A1essandro исправил ответ. На самом деле решение несколько иное.

Comment: спасибо, за подробное объяснение.

Comment: ваш ответ противоречит, приведённым в нём цитатам. Вы говорите: *"файл `__init__.py` не предназначен для хранения реализации общих для пакета функций"*, а затем цитируете *"special behavior for the `__init__.py` file, which is used to gather all package-wide definitions."* что буквально означает противоположное: особенность `__init__.py` в том, что собирает все определения общие для пакета (package-wide).

Comment: @TimofeiBondarev Спасибо за отличный ответ. Очень помогло.

Answer (score 4):

Внутри пакета к модулям при импортировании из других модулей обращаются через точку. Если к примеру в **__init__.py** имеется функция `create_app`, то в другом модуле лежащим в этой этой же папке импортирование этой функции будет таким:

```
from . import create_app
```

А если модуль в под-папке, то через две точки:

```
from .. import create_app
```

Подроблнее можно почитать либо в [официальной документации на docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/), либо в книге "Python. Подробный справочник. 4 издание" Девида Бизли с ISBN 978-5-93286-157-8, начиная со стр. 189

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с `python3.3+`, `__init__.py` не [обязателен](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448279):

> It used to be a required part of a package [old, pre-3.3 "regular
>   package"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages),
>   not [newer 3.3+ "namespace
>   package"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#namespace-packages)

Если Вы хотите включить тот или иной модуль в пакет, то нужно указать его в списке пакетов так, в `setup.py`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
setuptools.setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=['mypackage', 'mypackage.x'],
    package_data={
        'mypackage': ['data/hello.txt', '__x/*'],
    },
)
```

Также можно включать данные в пакет с помощью `package_data`. Если хотите включить директорию, то укажите `*`. ринципиального отличия между `package_data` и `packages`, я не увидел, за тем исключением, что в `package_data` можно включать и данные, и файлы `*.py`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121460/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-manifest-in-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121416/%d0%92%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121433/private-module-%d0%b2-python