# Какие бывают расширяемые архитектуры приложения на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Если брать ООП, сейчас я пытаюсь реализовать доступ к дочерним классам по принципу такого же вызова, как это происходит со свойствами. Я считаю, что это максимально читаемо, ведь, глядя на вызов, моментально становится ясно, от чего объект наследует. А последним элементом всегда будет метод или свойство.

Объясню подробнее. Итак, каталог:

```
cgi-bin
├── a.py
└── a
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── b.py
    └── b
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── c.py
        └── c
            └── ...
```

Содержимое модуля **a.py**:

```
class a:
  prop = 5
```

Содержимое модуля **b.py**:

```
class b (a):
  test = 7
```

Файлы **__init__.py** пакетов пусты. После импорта я пытался получить доступ следующим образом:

```
a.prop
a.b.prop
a.b.test
```

Но разумеется ничего не выходит, так как при:

```
import a
import a.b
```

приоритет импорта пакета выше, чем приоритет импорта модуля (пакет **a** и модуль **a** в одной директории). Если мой подход имеет право на жизнь, подскажите пожалуйста, как его привести в рабочее состояние, учитывая проблему с приоритетом импорта. Если есть более понятная и расширяемая архитектура, прошу продемонстрировать. Я только начинаю разбираться с языком. Спасибо!

Comment: Была попытка добавить `__all__ = ["a"]` в `__init__.py`, но результата не получил. Все так же импортируется только пакет.

Comment: А откуда происходит импорт `a`?

Comment: Можно первый импорт сделать в командной строке а потом в модуле `a`. Это к примеру. Главный вопрос в целом об архитектуре, конечно. И если это возможно, решить вопрос с приоритетом импорта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, вы чрезмерно усложняете структуру.

В вашей попытке решения уже есть проблема с тем, что довольно нетривиально импортировать модуль, имеющий совпадающее с пакетом имя.

Вторая проблема состоит в том, что класс и модуль будут разными объектами, и такое обращение к классам-наследникам, как вы планируете, не получится.

---

Для начала стоит подумать, действительно ли нужны классы, или достаточно модулей и функций. Затем нужно правильно разложить функциональность по модулям, при необходимости создавая вложенные пакеты.

Для того, чтобы доступ ко вложенным пакетам не требовал указания полного пути до объекта, в файлах `__init__.py` можно импортировать нужные объекты на уровень выше и далее. Про то, как использовать этот файл, можно почитать в вопросе [Обращение к функции заданной в __init__.py](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420987/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-init-py/420994#420994).

---

Тем не менее, при большом желании такое поведение всё же можно реализовать, используя метаклассы (решение приведено лишь для примера, использовать его в реальной программе не стоит):

```
class MagicianAncestor(type):
    def __init__(cls, what, bases=None, dict_=None):
        super().__init__(what, bases, dict_)

        for ancestor in bases:
            if type(ancestor) is not MagicianAncestor:
                continue
            setattr(ancestor, cls.__name__, cls)


class A(metaclass=MagicianAncestor):
    prop_a = 5


class B(A):
    prop_b = 10


class C(A):
    prop_c = 15


class D(B):
    prop_d = 20

a = A()
print(a.B.prop_b)    # 10
print(a.B.prop_a)    # 5
print(a.C.prop_c)    # 15
print(a.C.prop_a)    # 5
print(a.B.D.prop_d)  # 20
# print(a.D.prop_d)  # AttributeError
```

Comment: Я уже пытался реализовать через `__getattr__`. Получилось, но со своими приколами. Ваш вариант лаконичнее. Тем не менее, еще одна проблема состоит в том, что в файле дочернего класса тоже нужен импорт для родителя. Я уже порядком устал от этих зависимостей. Придется переходить на функции. Так как, возможно, это проще (прощай наследование...).

Comment: Через `__getattr__` я записывал в словарь присвоенный свойству для God объекта.

Comment: Возможно, вам и не нужно наследование. Можно обсудить вашу задачу в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27697/python--ru-so)