# Python 3 как правильно разделить на файлы программу

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Хочу разбить на файлы код, так как он громоздкий.

Делаю так:

**__init__.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import widget

root = tk.Tk()
#root.state("zoomed")

widget.echo(root)

root.mainloop()
```

**widget.py**

```
import tkinter as tk

def echo(tk):
    # Labels
    FirstLabel = tk.Label(root, text="x^2 + ", font="Arial 18")
    FirstLabel.grid(column=1,row=0)

    SecondLabel = tk.Label(root, text="x + ", font="Arial 18")
    SecondLabel.grid(column=3,row=0)

    ResultTextLabel = tk.Label(root, text = "Результат: ", font = "Arial 12")
    ResultTextLabel.grid(column = 2, row = 2)

    ResultLabel = tk.Label(root, text = "", font = "Arial 12")
    ResultLabel.grid(column = 2, row = 3)

    #Entrys
    EntryA = tk.Entry(root,width=5,bd=3)
    EntryA.grid(column=0,row=0)

    EntryB = tk.Entry(root,width=5,bd=3)
    EntryB.grid(column=2,row=0)

    EntryC = tk.Entry(root,width=5,bd=3)
    EntryC.grid(column=4,row=0)

    #Buttons

    btn = tk.Button(root,text="Решить")
    #btn.bind("<Button-1>",hello)
    btn.grid(column=2,row = 1)
```

Ошибка: **AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'Label'**

Comment: Пока перенес все GUI в отдельный файл, насколько это правильное решение?

Comment: я бы запуск из `__init__.py` в `main.py` перенес и перенес код в `if __name__ == '__main__':`, вам ведь не нужно чтобы при импорте приложение запустилось?

Comment: У вас в файле widgets.py имя аргумента tk совпадает с именем модуля tk, исправьте в первую очередь это

Comment: Я полагаю, что все ответы на ваш вопрос есть тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420987/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-init-py

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обращение к функции заданной в \_\_init\_\_.py](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420987/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-init-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

**__main__.py**

```
﻿import gui

def sumbit(event):
    result = findX(win.variable)
    if(result == 'Error'):
        win.ResultLabel['text'] = 'a - не может равнятся 0'
    else:
        win.ResultLabel['text'] = 'x1 = {0}, x2 = {1}'.format(result[0],result[1])

def findX(variable):
    try:
        D = (variable['b'].get() ** 2) - (4 * variable['a'].get() * variable['c'].get())

        x1 = (-variable['b'].get() + (D ** 0.5)) / (2 * variable['a'].get())
        x2 = (-variable['b'].get() - (D ** 0.5)) / (2 * variable['a'].get())

        return [x1,x2]
    except ArithmeticError:
        return 'Error'

win = gui.gui()

win.btn.bind("<Button-1>",sumbit)

win.root.mainloop()
```

**gui.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
class gui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.declareWidget()
        self.placeWidget()

    def declareWidget(self):
        #Labels
        self.FirstLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text="x^2 + ", font="Arial 18")
        self.SecondLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text="x + ", font="Arial 18")
        self.ResultTextLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Результат: ", font = "Arial 12")
        self.ResultLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text = "", font = "Arial 12")

        #Entrys
        self.variable = {'a': tk.IntVar(value = 1),'b': tk.IntVar(),'c': tk.IntVar()}
        self.EntryA = tk.Entry(self.root, width=5, bd=3, textvariable=self.variable['a'])       
        self.EntryB = tk.Entry(self.root, width=5, bd=3, textvariable=self.variable['b'])
        self.EntryC = tk.Entry(self.root, width=5, bd=3, textvariable=self.variable['c'])

        #Button
        self.btn = tk.Button(self.root,text="Решить")



    def placeWidget(self):
        # Labels
        self.FirstLabel.grid(column=1,row=0)
        self.SecondLabel.grid(column=3,row=0)
        self.ResultTextLabel.grid(column = 2, row = 2)
        self.ResultLabel.grid(column = 2, row = 3)  
        #Entrys
        self.EntryA.grid(column=0,row=0)        
        self.EntryB.grid(column=2,row=0)        
        self.EntryC.grid(column=4,row=0)    
        #Buttons            
        self.btn.grid(column=2,row = 1)
```