# Включить директории в пакет

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package

Собираю пакет `python`. Мне требуется, помимо `package`, которые содержат `__init__`, также включить и ряд директорий, которые не содержат его. Как это сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121460/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-manifest-in-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420987/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-init-py/1121453#1121453

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121433/private-module-%d0%b2-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Необходимо добавить](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) `package_data={'': ['cmd/*']},`:

```
setuptools.setup(
    name=version.app_name,
    version=version.app_version,
    package_data={'': ['cmd/*']},
)
```