# private module в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Можно ли создать приватный модуль, который будет виден только в рамках пакета?

Comment: Вроде нельзя. Непубличным пакетам/модулям обычно просто добавляют нижнее подчёркивание перед именем

Comment: @andreymal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547145/defining-private-module-functions-in-python нашёл это. Но не работает

Comment: А, ну, да... Вижу, нельзя

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602110/python-private-module-in-a-package

Comment: Можно `__`. Двойной префикс, как и всегда, делает модуль приватным.

Comment: Даже в классах двойной префикс не делает поля приватными, просто хитрым образом переименовывает. Ну а в модулях вообще ничего не делает, да

Comment: @andreymal `__` не добавляются в package, если этого явно не сказать.

Comment: Проверил, отлично добавляются и без явного указания, вероятно вы сами где-то накосячили

Comment: @andreymal да. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легко сдаётесь-с! Если прям очень хочется скрыть своё внутреннее АПИ от рук посторонних, есть у меня для вас одно извращение :))

Допустим у нас такой мини-проект:

```
project/
├─ pack/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  └─ hidden.py
└─ main.py
```

И хочется скрыть содержимое `hidden.py` от посторонних. Делаем так.

---

### `hidden.py`

Обычный код с логикой:

```py
import string, random

__all__ = [
    'make_secret_key', 'Super',
]

def make_secret_key():
    return ''.join(
        random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
        for _ in range(10)
    )

class Super:
    def __init__(self, x='42'):
        self.x = x

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Super({self.x})'
```

---

### `__init__.py`

Техноколдовство здесь:

```py
import sys

__all__ = [
    'make_some_object'
]

# Мелочь для удобства
class dotdict(dict):
    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__

# Делаем замыкание
def prepare():
    from . import hidden

    # Почему-то эта манипуляция не очень полезна
    # и не мешает работе import pack.hidden
    sys.modules[hidden.__name__] = None

    # Зато можно почистить модуль от его содержимого
    # переложив его в локальную переменную
    local_hidden = dotdict()
    for name in hidden.__all__:
        local_hidden[name] = getattr(hidden, name)
        delattr(hidden, name)
    delattr(hidden, '__all__')

    # Будто ничего и не скрывалось!
    hidden = local_hidden

    # Здесь объявляем классы/функции/переменные,
    # для работы которых нужен скрываемый модуль
    def make_some_object():
        return hidden.Super(hidden.make_secret_key())

    # Перекладываем их в текущий модуль
    # При желании можно автоматизировать используя местный "__all__"
    this = sys.modules[__name__]
    setattr(this, 'make_some_object', make_some_object)
    delattr(this, 'prepare')

    # Вуаля, реальный hidden теперь бесполезен,
    # а local_hidden недоступен извне!

    # Возможно есть уязвимость к importlib.reload(pack.hidden)
    # но её можно постараться исправить

prepare()
```

---

### `main.py`

Типа юзер, пытающийся использовать запретный модуль:

```
import pack.hidden as hidden

try:
    print(hidden.Super)
except AttributeError:
    print('** Невозможно обратиться к полю внутреннего модуля!')
```

---

Конечно, здесь скрыт не сам модуль, а его содержимое, зато скрыто оно довольно жёстко.

Comment: Ну, кажется, что лучше такого не делать вообще. Иначе у человека, который будет смотреть, что происходит в коде, вскипит моск. Спасибо за решение.

Comment: Я встречал код куда запутаннее, ещё и без комментариев, для решения куда менее важных задач, вдохновило  И если защищаться реально надо, то вполне себе вариант, особенно если с подробными комментариями для коллег и себя в будущем.

Comment: `Super = pack.make_some_object.__closure__[0].cell_contents.Super`

Comment: Ну и в целом `local_hidden = pack.make_some_object.__closure__[0].cell_contents`

Comment: @andreymal Надо же, насколько в Питоне глубока интроспекция! Спасибо за инфу. Во всяком случае, достать значения при желании можно и из бинаря, зато описанный способ обеспечивает куда больший уровень приватности, чем просто соглашения о подчёркиваниях.

Comment: Кстати, раз класс dotdict не спрятан, то можно ещё [найти все экземпляры этого класса через gc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/328882)

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя. Но для того, чтобы придерживаться некоторых соглашений, используют `__` для `private` и `_` для `protected`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=['mypackage'],
    package_data={
        'mypackage': ['data/hello.txt'],
    },
)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121460/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-manifest-in-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121416/%d0%92%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420987/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-init-py/1121453#1121453