# Что такое MANIFEST.in и зачем он нужен?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, pip

Для чего используется этот файл?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121433/private-module-%d0%b2-python

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121416/%d0%92%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420987/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-init-py/1121453#1121453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный файл нужен для того, чтобы указывать, какие файлы следует включить в сборку пакета. [Пример](https://klen.github.io/create-python-packages.html#manifest-in):

[MANIFEST.in](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/):

```
include mypackage/data/hello.txt
```

setup.py:

```
import setuptools


setuptools.setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=['mypackage'],
    include_package_data=True
)
```

Здесь файлы перечисляются не в `setup.py`, а в `MANIFEST.in`. Можно гибко управлять добавлением или исключением файлов.В официальной документации это [есть](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/). Главное тут не забыть `include_package_data=True`.

Другой способ включить файлы:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='mypackage',
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=['mypackage'],
    package_data={
        'mypackage': ['data/hello.txt'],
    },
)
```